# C++: Solve linear system with Lapack and transpose right hand side

Tags: c++, lapack

I have matrices `H` and `C`, where `H` is invertible, and I want to solve the linear system with multiple right hand side

```
HX=C'
```

Where `C'` denotes matrix transpose. If I had to solve the system

```
HX=C
```

I would simple call the Lapack routines `dgetrs_` and `dgetrf_` to obtain the solution. However, I do not have the right hand side matrix directly available, but only the transpose one.

What is the fastest way of tackling this problem? I know that I could loop over `C` to obtain its transpose, but I wish I could do better than that.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Looking at the source of the wrapper of LAPACK named LAPACKE, the function [`LAPACKE_dgetrs_work()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d4/d08/lapacke__dgetrs__work_8c_source.html) transposes both the matrix and the right hand side if `LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR ` is used. Therefore, it seems that tranposing the matrices makes sense... Could the functions `LAPACKE_dgetrs()` and `LAPACKE_dgetrf()` solve your problem?

Comment: Hey @francis, thank you for suggesting that approach. However, in the [LAPACKE Documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html) you can read literally:

"_Note that using row-major ordering may require more memory and time than column-major ordering, because the routine must transpose the row-major order to the column-major order required by the underlying LAPACK routine._"

I am pretty sure that LAPACKE will invert the matrix faster than I would ever dream of, but this is exactly the overhead I would like to get rid of

Comment: Notice that the cost of the overhead is limited. Indeed, its complexity is O(n^2), while the complexity of the LU decomposition is O(n^3). The source code of LAPACKE_dgetrf() and LAPACKE_dgetrs() can be combined to avoid transposing the array A twice. Notice that `dgetrf()` computes a PLU decompostion of A^T. Then, dgetrs() could be used with option 'T'. But the right-hand side would still have to be transposed.

Comment: To be sure, all your matrices, X, A, C are already stored in column-major format?

Comment: I can confirm that LapackE, when used with matrices in  row major order,  systematically performs copies of the matrices to transform them into the column major order before calling the legacy lapack subroutine.

Comment: Yes @PicaudVincent, my matrices are stored in column-major format. However, since I never use the right-hand side as a non-transposed matrix, I think I will switch to column-major format --that should work, ain't it?

Comment: @enanone Yes, if you only use C^t, maybe it is simpler to only store its transpose, in column-major format and call it something like Ct. On my side I checked the idea of writing HX=C^t <=> X^t.H^t=C, then use H=PLU etc... you can do all the job without extra C copy, but you end up with X^t... I fear that if you do not want to do extra copy at the beginning to transpose C, you have to do it a the end to transpose the solution. Finally I think Francis is right with its pragmatic approach, a copy is only O(n^2)...which does not weight a lot compared to the O(n^3) for solving the system.